# Why this stored procedure doesn't work?

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

It doesn't seem like there is a problem, I can't understand why doesn't return data.

This is my stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`.`get_products`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE  `test`.`get_products`
(
    OUT out_productName VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
SELECT productName INTO out_productName FROM products;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

and this is how I call it:

```
$rs = mysql_query( 'CALL get_products(@f)' );
$rs = mysql_query( 'SELECT @f' );
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
{
print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: The use of mysql_* commands is old and insecure.  You should really look into using [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) for your mysql interactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this doesn't quite answer your question but a work around is to just not to use the output parameter

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`.`get_products`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE  `test`.`get_products`
(

)
BEGIN
SELECT productName INTO @f FROM products;
END $$
DELIMITER ;


 mysql_query( 'set @f = 0;' );
$rs = mysql_query( 'CALL get_products()' );
$rs = mysql_query( 'SELECT @f' );
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
{
print_r($row);
}
```

@f will be maintained by the database and can be accessed for the sql session, if I remember correctly

also in the event that you would be returning things while getting results from the stored procedure you would also want to use

```
$rs->close();
 $connection->next_result();
```

connection would be whatever you named your connection string

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test.get_products;
CREATE PROCEDURE  test.get_products()
BEGIN
SELECT productName FROM products;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

And call it:

```
$rs = mysql_query( 'CALL test.get_products()' );
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
{
    print_r($row);
}
```